# Why does $b^n = b^{n-1} b$ require $n>0$ where $n$ is an integer?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm reading The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 1 and it says that $b^n = b^{n-1} b$ if $n>0$

But I've always used it even when $n \le 0$ in my years of engineering math classes.  Whats going on?

Comment: Maybe he assumed $n>0$ because he was only interested in $n>0$ at that part of the book.

Comment: what If b=0=n..

Comment: But in general is it right that n can be any integer? @Integral

Comment: @JohnDoe I dont think that he cared for that case because he also states $b^n = b^{n+1} / b$ if $n<0$

Comment: Hmm. ... well, technically speaking it's true.  Just like "$b^n = b^{n-1}b$ if babar is an elephant is true".  Okay... I think the book simply hasn't yet *defined* what $b^n$ means if $n < 0$ so as far as the book knows $b^{n < 0}$ isn't defined yet.  As it turns out $b^n = b^{n-1}b$ is true not just for $n > 0$ but $n < 0$ and $n \in \mathbb Q$ and $n\in \mathbb R$ and if $n$ is a complex number.  But what any of those *mean* hasn't been defined yet.

Comment: For all $b$ and $n> 0$ $n$ and integer. then $b^n = b^{n-1}b$ but this is not true if $b = 0$ and $n \le 0$.  Then $b^0$ or $b^{neg}$ are not defined.  If $b \ne 0$ then this is true for an integers $n$.  If $b> 0$ then then is true for all rational, real, and complex n, but $b^n$ needs to be defined.  This is not true for $b < 0$ are $b^n$ might not be defined for rational or real n.  But it is defined and true for complex $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, wait!  I get it.

This a *programming* book and they are trying to get you used to the idea of *defining* things recursively.

They are claiming it is the *definition* that if $b \ne 0$ and $n\in \mathbb Z$.

Then $b^n$ is *defined* as:

$$\begin{align}
\text{If $n = 0$ then } b^0 &:= 1 \\
\text{If $n > 0$ then } b^n &:= b^{n-1}\cdot b \\
\text{If $n < 0$ then } b^n &:= \frac {b^{n+1}}b \\
\end{align}$$

So to figure out what $2^5$ is you figure out what $2^4$ is and then multiply that by $2$.  To figure out what $2^4$ is you figure out what $2^3$ is and then multiply that be $2$.  And so on.  Eventually you will figure that $2^0=1$ so $2^1 = 2\cdot1=2$ and $2^2 = 2\cdot2^1 = 2\cdot2=4$ and $2^3 = 2\cdot2^2 = 2\cdot4=8$ and so on....

It *is* a true fact that $b^n= b^{n-1}b$ for whatever value $n$ is. But if I use that to *calculate* $3^{-2}$ I will get an infinite loop.  $$3^{-2} = 3^{-3}\cdot3 = 3^{-4}\cdot3\cdot3 = 3^{-5}\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3 = \cdots$$ are all true, but I will never get a resolution.

So, $$b^n = b^{n-1}\cdot b = \frac {b^{n+1}}b$$ is a *true* statement, always. But it is not an acceptable *definition*.

---

A *basic* subroutine to calculate $b^n$ can be written as:

`function exp (float b, int n){
...if (n == 0)
.......return 1;
...if (n > 0)
.......return b*exp(b, n-1);
...if (n < 0){
......if (b ==0) return Nan;
......return exp(b,n+1)/b;
}`

Comment: Once $b^n$ for $n > 0$ has been defined, then I would define $b^{-n}$ as the solution to $(b^n)(b^{-n}) = 1$. In both cases, you need to prove that $b^{j+k} = b^jb^k$, and that is not trivial.

Comment: I never said this was a *good* way to define $b^n$.  I said this was the *book's* way... for tthe purpose of teaching the would be programmer how to do recursive defining. That you have I have ways we'd prefer is irrelevent  And I'm not sure why you say proving $b^{j+k} = b^jb^k$ is not trivial.  It is very easy via induction.

Comment: What do you induct on? The proof may not be that difficult, but I would not call it trivial.

Comment: @martycohen Isn't the induction proof just as follows? (for $j > 0, k>0$) Basis: $k=1$, trivial using definition.  Hypothesis: $b^{j+k} = b^j b^k$ Step: $b^{j+k+1} = b^{j+k} b$ = $b^j b^{k+1}$ ? The other 5 cases would be similar.

Comment: @jason exactly.  I would call that immediate and ... trivial.  I mean, didn't we all learn that in the 5th grade or earlier?  Although we was thinking double induction.  Show that for all $k$ that $b^kb = b^{k+1}$ by induction and the show byin indection for all $j$ that $b^kb^j = b^{k+1}$.  A double index back and forth induction.